# Android unit tests won't use correct Application class

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, robolectric

I'm experiencing some strange behavior with respect to how android chooses the `Application` class in unit tests.

I have Robolectric unit tests in the directory `src/testDevelopmentDebug`

I also have some test code I share between `src/testDevelopmentDebug` and `androidTestDevelopment` for unit tests and espresso tests respectively. The shared code is in `src/sharedTest` and I have this setup in my `build.gradle` file like this:

```
sourceSets {
    // Android Studio / the Android Studio Kotlin Plugin will stop recognizing these source folders as source
    // folders without explicitly setting them
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    testDevelopmentDebug.java.srcDirs += 'src/testDevelopmentDebug/kotlin'
    androidTestDevelopment.java.srcDirs += 'src/androidTestDevelopment/kotlin'

    // Share code between UI and unit tests.
    def sharedTestDir = 'src/sharedTest/kotlin'
    androidTestDevelopment.java.srcDirs += sharedTestDir
    testDevelopmentDebug.java.srcDirs += sharedTestDir
}
```

My issue is that I'm trying to share an `Application` class between the two, but it isn't entirely working. I have `SharedTestApplication` in the shared test folder. But when I reference it in the `testDevelopmentDebug/AndroidManifest.xml` file like this:

```
<application android:name="com.books.sharedtest.SharedTestApplication"/>
```

The Espresso tests use `SharedTestApplication` like I would expect.

The unit tests default back to my `src/main` `Application` class and use that instead. Now here's the weird part. If I extend `SharedTestApplication` in `src/testDevelopmentDebug` and do nothing else. (Not even changing the manifests) then it uses the `SharedTestApplication` like I want it to.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Robolectric** is loading default `AndroidManifest.xml` unless you specify different manifest in `@Config`. You can also specify application class in `@Config` as well.

Check more in the [tutorial](http://robolectric.org/configuring/).

Comment: So specifying the `AndroidManifest.xml` didn't help me because my `src/testDevelopmentDebug/AndroidManifest.xml` wasn't being generated into the build output at all. If it had been, I'm sure I could've fixed it that way. Instead, I used `@Config(application = SharedTestApplication::class)` which fixed my issue. I also created a base test class to put the robolectric config on, since that saved me having to duplicate that config on all the test classes.

Comment: That is another option that I suggested for fix in the answer :) Great that you solved it!

Comment: Haha, super short answer, but I somehow managed to not read all if it?